# Send form using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to send the form in its entirety, using ajax.

The form has an Id which is 'FormId'.

```
const Url = '/CV/AutoSave/';
    var testForm = $('#FormId');
    var cvForm = new FormData(testForm[0]);
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: Url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            data: cvForm,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result.Id)
            }
        });
```

When debugging the code I can see that testForm is equal to the entire form.

```
var cvForm = new FormData(testForm[0]);
```

Is empty for some reason.

The form has many fields, so I hope it is possible to send the entire form, instead of defining every single field in js before sending them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the form fields all have `name=""` on them?  Are they all non disabled?

Comment: this code seems to be functionally right. you may want to check your jQuery version and `name` attributes of each fields as @Taplar has mentioned.

Comment: All of them have names, as it works to push the submit button manually. The thing is that I want js to autosave the form.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `FormData`, the content type should be `multipart/form-data`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You should also use `processData: false` to prevent jQuery from trying to serialize the `FormData` object.

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: Url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        processData: false,
        data: cvForm,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.Id)
        }
    });
```

If the form doesn't have any file uploads, you can use `$('#FormId').serialize()` to serialize it in URL-encoded format, then your `$.ajax` call would work. You don't need the `contentType` option, it defaults correctly.

Comment: I see. The form has file uploads. But cvForm is empty before it tries to send it.

Comment: How do you know it's empty?

Comment: When I debug, I can see that cvForm = FormData {} without any content, I would presume that this is an indication that it is empty.

Comment: Try this: `foo = new FormData; foo.append("name", "val"); console.log(foo);`. You won't see anything, yet the object obviously has data in it. It's just that `FormData` doesn't show its contents.

Comment: If you want to see what's being sent, look at the AJAX request in the Network tab of the console.

Comment: I see now that the data is being sent, however, it does not look the same as when sending the form directly. It seems like it is not recognized as a form.

Comment: How is it different from when sending the form normally?

Comment: One of those is the raw payload, the other is decoded. Is there a reason you're using `FormData` in the first place? It's only needed if you're trying to upload a file.

Comment: The thing is that the form contains an input field, where they can upload an image. Should I send them separately?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `contentType` to `false` so proper `Content-Type` header with correct `boundary` will be set. Also set `processData` to `false` to prevent jQuery serializing data

```
const Url = '/CV/AutoSave/';
var testForm = $('#FormId');
var cvForm = new FormData(testForm[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: cvForm,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.Id)
    }
});
```